# Multiple tables vs one table with more columns

Tags: sql, mongodb, database-design, nosql, relational-database

My chosen database is MongoDB. But the question should be independent.

So for example, each row of record will have a flag that can take 1 of 2 possible values.

What is the pro and con of:

- Having 1 table with a column to hold the value of this flag.

versus:

the pro and con of:

- Having 2 tables to hold the two different types of records distinguished by the aforementioned flag?
- Would this be cheaper in terms of storage, since you don't have that extra column?
- Would this also be faster in queries, since you know exactly which table to look without having to perform a filter?

What is the common practice in industry?

Comment: Do you have an example? You are wrong, it can make a big difference whether you have a NoSQL database like MongoDB or a relational RDBMS.

Comment: Can you explain why NoSQL vs relational RDBMS would make a difference? And the example that I have is as basic as descried in the ticket.

Comment: NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins (some of them even do not support joins at all).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Given that these 2 tables are actually the same entity, one would not expect any joins? At most, we would have to perform a union to combine them into 1?

Answer (score 1):

Storage for a single column holding just a flag (e.g. `active` and `archived`) should be negligible. The query could be faster with two tables, however your application is more complex, you have to write 2 queries.

When you have only 2 distinct values and these values are more or less evenly distributed, then an index will not be used, thus the performance should be equal - unless you select the entire table.

It might be useful to have 2 tables if the flags are not evenly distributed. For example you have a rather small `active` data set which is queried frequently, and a big `archive` data set which is much bigger but hardly queried.

If available, you can also work with partitions which is actually a good combination of both.

Comment: Why if the 2 flag values are evenly distributed then "and index will not be used"? And why would the performance be equal when no index is used? Why selecting the entire table will cause a different performance outcome?

Comment: An index is only used if it is selective. When an indexed column has only 2 values and each values appears in app. 50% of all rows then the index is useless and not used (unless you have special Bitmap-Index on Oracle).

Comment: Selecting all rows from a table with 1 million rows, takes longer then selection all from a table having only 0.5 million of rows.